# Delete image out of array at given index

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uiscrollview

I have created and initialized a scrollview that pulls from an array of images. So a user swipes past a photo, then another, and I need to delete the image based on the location of the current image I have created a for loop that deletes the image i-- in the array, but this crashes because I can't delete the i. Is there a way I can accomplish this? Thank you: here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        for i in 0..<imageArray.count {
            if i >= 3 {
                imageArray.remove(at: i - 2)
            }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai6"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai7"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai4"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai3"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai5"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DigitalDrawingPreview"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "denarus"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dubai1")]
for i in 0..<imageArray.count  {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = imageArray[i]
    let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

    mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
    mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Comment: This code example isn't really complete, can you add the full example.

Comment: I believe this is all my code I can check but I'm pretty sure this what I got, just a scroll view with images john_ryan 36

Comment: Ok i assumed there would be some code that handled the scroll, otherwise how would you remove the last image once the user scrolled to the next

Comment: Good point let me get that part make take a few minutes

Comment: john_ryan i added the scrollviewdidscroll method check it out, still not working

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a UIScrollView, I would recommend using a UITableView or UICollectionView.  It is very easy to manage the data model and then call `table.reloadData()`.

You would track the scroll position with the ScrollViewDelegate method `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView)` and force a reload once you've scrolled far enough.

Comment: dmorrow I cannot use a table view, so ill try using the reload idea in the did scroll

Comment: @RandyWindin Why can't you use a table view?  It's just a scroll view with external logic about how to place repeating objects.

Comment: well it is a horozontial scroll not verticle, i created this to see images that you can scroll through like on your photo album on your phone.

Comment: The you should use a UICollectionView, which can scroll in either direction.  This use case is exactly the type of thing it is designed for.